# Where to get Ubuntu One for iPad?

Tags: ubuntu-one, ipad

The download page for iPhone and iPad seems only to offer apps for iPhone. I need one for iPad. Is one available? If so where?

Answer (score 2):

I have U1 on ipad.  However,  the app is not yet optimized for ipad sized screen.  It still works though.  Just download it and use it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ubuntu One app in the Itunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ubuntu-one-files/id489935140?mt=8) app store says:

> Requirements: Compatible with iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad. Requires iOS 4.3 or later. This app is optimized for iPhone 5.

So it should be compatible with your iPad.  What page where you looking at?  Maybe you need to update iOS?